# How to organize useState and useQuery - Apollo/Graphql

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

I'm trying to pass data from useState([]) to the variables for filtering products. It works, but on very strange way.

When I click on a category checkbox, it is not checked, but the products are filtered, when I click on another category, again checkbox didn't checked, but already two values in the array useState([1,2]), and when I click again, the checkbox is checked, but is removed from the array useState([]).

```
const GET_PRODUCTS = gql`
    query GetProducts($filterByCategory: [ID]) {
        products(filters: {category: {id:{in: $filterByCategory}}}) {
        ....
        }
    }
`
const VacanciesPage = () => {
    const [selectCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState([]);
    
    const getSetSelectedCategories = (category) => {
        console.log(category);
        if(selectCategories.includes(category)){
            setSelectedCategories(selectCategories.filter(item => item != category));
            return;
        }
        setSelectedCategories([...selectCategories, category]);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(selectCategories);
    },[selectCategories]);

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS, {
        variables: { "filterByCategory": selectCategories},
    });

    if (loading) return null;
    if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;

    const { products, categories } = data;

    return(
        {categories.data.map(category => (
            <label key={category.id} className="inline-flex items-center mt-3 mr-3">
                <input type="checkbox" className="w-5 h-5" value={category.id} onChange={e => getSetSelectedCategories(+e.target.value)}/><span className="ml-2 text-gray-700">{category.attributes.name}</span>
            </label>
        ))}
    );
}
```

Comment: You have a typo `+` in `getSetSelectedCategories(+e.target.value)`

Comment: @Operator this is not a typo, this is for converting String to Int, the same as Number(e.target.value).

Comment: For the checkboxes to work properly you need to use controlled inputs it's described in the react docs https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components.

Also always strive towards simplify your code and make it more readable since this prevents bugs. Why is this function called `getSetSelectedCategories` if it's only setting it should be called `setSelectedCategories`. Plus use the Number() operator instead of the implicit + operator to avoid confusion imo.

Answer (score 0):

I completely rewrote the code, moved the variables to a separate function and everything finally worked.

```
    const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState([]);
    const [searchStatus, setSearchStatus] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(selectedCategories);
    },[selectedCategories]);
    
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS);
    const { loading: loadingCategories, error: errorCategories, data: categories } = useQuery(GET_CATEGORIES);
    const [ getFilteredProducts, 
        { loading: filterLoading, error: filterError, data: filteredProducts } 
    ] = useLazyQuery(FILTER_PRODUCTS_QUERY);

    if (loading || loadingCategories || filterLoading) return "Loading";
    if (error || errorCategories || filterError) return `Error! ${error}`;
    
    const { products: allProducts } = data;
    const { categories: allCategories } = categories;

    const clearSearch = () => {
        setSelectedCategories([]);
        setSearchStatus(false);
    };

    const searchProducts = () => {
        let filter = {};
        setSearchStatus(true);
        if (Object.keys(filter).length === 0) {
            if (!selectedCategories) {
                setSearchStatus(false);
                return;
            }
        }
        getFilteredProducts({
            variables: {
                filterByCategories: selectedCategories
                ? selectedCategories
                : allCategories.data.map((category) => category.id),
            },
        });
    };

    const dataset = searchStatus && filteredProducts ? filteredProducts?.products : allProducts;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).